# SQLite3 select field by numeric range

Tags: iphone, sqlite, floating-point, range

in SQLite3, say i have this simple table

```
rowid     value1    value2
(int)     (float)   (float)  
1         15.3      20.2
2         17.8      30.5
3         15.8      25.3
4         16.1      48.0
```

How could I select those rows where the values are:
15.0 >= value1 <= 16.5   - effectively selecting rows 1,2 & 3

further
how can i refine adding to the first criteria this to ALSO
20.0 >= value2 <= 37.0 - selecting then only row 1 & 3?

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your first logic is not correct, for if value1 is less than 15, it will also be less than 16.5, but just change the operators:

Select * from SimpleTable where value1 <= 15.0 and value1 <= 16.5;

Maybe you meant:

Select * from SimpleTable where value1 >= 15.0 and value1 <= 16.5;

Again (considering the adjusted logic):

Select * from SimpleTable where value1 >= 15.0 and value1 <= 16.5 and value2 >= 20.0 and value2 <= 37.0;

You might want to add and "order by" clause if you want your results sorted.

Comment: oh! but I'm already usng a where clause for another field (say, TYPE='w'). Rght now my clause is: SELECT * from EN where TYPE='W'; I need to know I I could further filter the rest of the results. Can I use two or more Where statements in sqlite3?

Comment: You can use AND to add further where clauses, as I did above.

Comment: Select * from EN where TYPE='W' and value1 >= 15.0 and value1 <= 16.5;

Comment: Orwen you are right on the logic i used on my example, just a bit burnt out from the last couple of days coding

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute the SQL command below :

```
select id, value1, value2 FROM <table name> WHERE value1 >= 15.0 AND  value1 <= 16.5 AND value2 >= 20.0 AND value2 <= 37.0
```