# SQLite3 select field by numeric range, Expanded, pt2

Tags: sqlite, floating-point, range

I just asked (and was kindly answered)

This question:
[SQLite3 select field by numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313777/sqlite3-select-field-by-numeric-range)

But now if I have the table

```
rowid     value1    value2    type
(int)     (float)   (float)   (char)
1         15.3      20.2      W
2         17.8      30.5      W
3         15.8      25.3      S
4         16.1      48.0      WT
```

How can select those rows where *type='W' & type='S' and 15 <= value1 <= 16.6 and 30.0 <= value2 <=30.0* ?

I try as someone suggested on my previous question to use `AND`, but for the strings something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EN WHERE type='S' and type='W';
```

Does not work, it returns an empty result (I'm using SQLite manager extension for Firefox).

And there are hundreds of both W, S, WT types in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   en 
WHERE  ( TYPE = 'S' 
          OR TYPE = 'W' ) 
       AND ( value1 BETWEEN 15 AND 16.6 
             AND value2 BETWEEN 30.0 AND 40.0 )
```

Comment: thank you brother. stackoverflow's got to be the best invention since sliced bread!